# How to access dynamically created element id in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to access dynamically created id using jQuery.

I am creating `<li>` element dynamically and adding id to it while creating it using following code.

```
<?php foreach ($alerts as $a) : ?>

<li id="<?php echo $a['value']['alert_name']; ?>"><?php echo $a['value']['alert_name']; ?> <a href="#" class="edit-link tip-open" data-oid="<?php echo $a['oid']; ?>" data-eid="<?php echo $a['value']['alert_name']; ?>">edit</a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here I have added id to li element using php array's value.

Now I want remove that li using their id.My problem is that When I write `(#id).remove()` its not removing that li element from page.

When I checked page view source I found that Id is not there and when I press F5 id is there.

Please help me to delete that li element using their dynamically assigned id withour reloading the page.

I am trying to remove that li using following code in anither file called jquery-func.js:

```
$("#"+response['aname']).remove();
```

here response array contains name of the id.

As per my analysis jquery is not getting that dynamic id because when press F5 li is able to remove

Comment: IDs must be unique in context page. Provide rendered HTML instead of unreadable PHP code

Comment: Improve your question by posting relevant code. How are you trying to remove li element???

Answer (score 1):

You can try like

```
$("li[id='"+id+"']").remove();
```

or this will also work

```
$("#"+id).remove();
```

And makesure that `id` should be different and not duplicate

Comment: If duplicate IDs, this will remove all but yes usually this is how to deal with uggly code ;) The second one will only works for first matched element

Comment: I don't think that this will make any difference

Comment: I think he didnt had duplicate ids

Comment: So no reason to use first solution

Comment: since he didnt have ....what is the problem with first code

Comment: Slower than using classic one and less readable make it useless. This just can be a workaround for duplicate IDs

Comment: And also I have given 2 ans....have you seen that...??

Comment: May it is less readable but it is not useless .....@roasted

Comment: What i didn't have spotted first is that OP was not using '$', maybe just a typo or you have spotted it right

Comment: Yes I obey with u 100% and he cont directly select like $(#id) since id is not a constant

Comment: +1 IMO most accurate answer here

Answer (score 1):

To select dynamically created HTML elements.

Now you have to use `.on()`.

Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the element by identifying it by its class:

```
<?php foreach ($alerts as $a) : ?>

<li id="<?php echo $a['value']['alert_name']; ?>"><?php echo $a['value']['alert_name']; ?> <a href="#" class="edit-link tip-open" data-oid="<?php echo $a['oid']; ?>" data-eid="<?php echo $a['value']['alert_name']; ?>">edit</a>
<a class="yourClass">delete</a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
$(".yourClass").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
<?php echo $a['value']['alert_name']; ?>
```

like ID name

then you should use this value name with #

I guess the value of this php echo is for exampe "foo"

then I use:

```
$('#foo').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not relying on the ID or any indicator, You can try like this

```
<li>
  <a class="rmv">test</a>
</li>
```

in your Jquery

```
$('.rmv').click(function(){
  $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete li then it is very simple:

**Java Script Code:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.delete').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php 
$alerts = array('Apple','Banana','Cat');
foreach ($alerts as $i => $a) : ?>
<li id="li_<?php echo $i;?>">
    <?php echo $a; ?> 
    <a href="#" class="edit-link tip-open" data-oid="<?php echo $a; ?>" data-eid="<?php echo $a; ?>">edit</a>
     | 
    <a href="#" class='delete'>delete</a></li>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I hope you understand :)